# How I can increase the background merge threads in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm using clickhouse to store stock prices on a win10 machine via docker/wsl2.

My computer has 128GB ram and 12 cores, so I set the wsl2 to use 64GB and 8 cores, which I can confirm the numbers in docker container.

However, after inserting half billion records into the clickhouse, I continously see there are ~16-20 background merge threads running by checking system.metrics. And it only take ~200% cpu and 1GB ram. I tried to delete some rows from one of the tables, and the mutation job never starts.

I've set the config.xml to be like

```
<merge_tree>
  <parts_to_delay_insert>1000</parts_to_delay_insert> 
  <parts_to_throw_insert>1200</parts_to_throw_insert> 
  <max_part_loading_threads>20</max_part_loading_threads> 
</merge_tree>
```

and users.xml to be like

```
<max_memory_usage>60000000000</max_memory_usage>
<background_pool_size>64</background_pool_size>
<background_move_pool_size>32</background_move_pool_size>
```

the number of partitions is set to be around 1500 for each table. and insertion happens every 100K records come.

Is there anything I did wrong? How can I set the clickhouse engine to use maximum resource given?

Thanks!

Comment: You have pretty week machine, you don't need to tune merge pools. Why are doing this?

Comment: >and the mutation job never starts.
share `select * from system.mutations where not is_done format Vertical`

Comment: database:                   db_stock
table:                      stock_bars_15min
mutation_id:                mutation_425.txt
"command:                    DELETE WHERE some_key IN (SELECT key_id FROM some_table)"
create_time:                2022-02-28 03:41:11
block_numbers.partition_id: ['']
block_numbers.number:       [425]
"parts_to_do_names:          ['5c..._1_1_0',..._423_423_0']"
parts_to_do:                423
is_done:                    0
latest_failed_part:         
latest_fail_time:           1970-01-01 00:00:00
latest_fail_reason:

Comment: the machine may not be as good as some servers. but it's the mechanism that confuses me. the alter delete query was inited 2 days ago, but not started. what I assume is there are tons of merging jobs to be done before the mutation. that's why I would want to accelerate the merging part by utilizing more resources. anything that may help?

Comment: Most probably the problem is wsl2. wsl2 does not support some functions which needed. Try virtual box.